# Web scraping with lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

How to extract text between  tags using xpath? For example, I tried to extract text that starts with "Area:" , the following code extracted only the word "Area" and not the following text.

`tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)`

`xpath_ex= '//b[contains(text(),"Area:")]/descendant::text()'`

`raw_ex = tree.xpath(xpath_ex)`

Comment: Can you post a representative chunk of your `response.text`?

Comment: <div class="text"><h4>ABC, Assistant Professor&nbsp;</h4>
<p><b>Area:</b>&nbsp;Natural Language Processing, Artificial Intelligence, Computer Graphics, Computer Vision<a href=" http://www.somelink/people/Faculty/Profile/ABC.html"></a></p>
<p><a href="/computing/people/faculty/ABC.html">Profile &amp; Contact Information&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;| &nbsp;Home Page</p>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html posted in your comment is incomplete but assuming it looks something like this:

```
 resp = """
    <div class="text"><h4>ABC, Assistant Professor&nbsp;</h4> 
      <p><b>Area:</b>&nbsp;Natural Language Processing, Artificial Intelligence, 
Computer Graphics, Computer Vision<a href=" somelink/people/Faculty/Profile/ABC.html"></a> </p> <p>  <a href="/computing/people/faculty/ABC.html">Profile &amp; Contact Information&nbsp;</a>  &nbsp;| &nbsp;Home Page</p> 
    </div>
"""
```

try this:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
tree = fromstring(resp)

xpath_ex= tree.xpath('//div[@class="text"]/p')
print(xpath_ex[0].text_content())
```

Output:

> Area: Natural Language Processing, Artificial Intelligence, Computer Graphics, Computer Vision